# How to select specific element of xml input log in Logstash

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, logstash

I'm setting logstash for being able to receive xml logs from filebeat. The problem I'm facing on is that I don't want to print the whole log file, I'm just interested in specific fields. To do so I'm using xml filter plugin and Prune filter plugin.

For example, I'm working with IDMEF-Message alerts, and I'm interested in the Classification field.

The configuration I did is:

```
input {
    beats {
        port => "5044"
    }
}

#I'm just interested in the log alert.
filter {    
  prune {      
    whitelist_names => [ "^message$"]
  }    
}    

#Get de classification text from the alert
filter {    
  xml {
    source => "message"
    store_xml => false
    target => "clasifications"
    xpath => ["/IDMEF-Message/Alert/Classification/text()", "clasificacion"]
    remove_field => "message"
  }
}

#Add a new field class with the clasifications value
filter {    
  mutate{add_field=>{"class"=>"%{clasifications}"}}
}

#remove message and just let the class field
filter {    
  prune {    
    whitelist_names => [ "clas"]
  }    
}  

output {
 file {
   path => "~/xml_logstash.txt"
 }
}
```

And the output I'm receiving is just {"class":"%{clasifications}"}. I also tried changing  mutate{add_field=>{"class"=>"%{clasifications}"}} to  mutate{add_field=>{"class"=>"%{clasificacion}"}}, but the result is the same.

My doubt is how to access to the "clasificacion" field where I stored the result of the xml filter.

An example of the logs I'm working on is:

```
<IDMEF-Message>
   <Alert messageid="...">
      <Analyzer ...
      </Analyzer>
      <CreateTime ... </CreateTime>
      <DetectTime ... </DetectTime>
      <AnalyzerTime ... </AnalyzerTime>
      <Source> 
        ...
      </Source>
      <Target>
         ...
      </Target>
      <Classification text="Text_Class" />
<IDMEF-Message>
```

Thank you
Rubi

Answer (score 1):

I solved it.

The problem was the way I accessed the text attribute of the classification field. You have to use @text if it is an attribute, and text() in case is the value of a field.

```
filter {

  xml {
    source => "message"
    store_xml => false
    target => "clasifications"
    xpath => ["/IDMEF-Message/Alert/Classification/@text", "clasificacion"]
   }
}

filter {

  mutate{add_field=>{"clasificacion"=>"%{clasificacion}"}}

}
```